# Multiple users but storing data in same tables

Tags: c#, asp.net, database

Hi I am new to databases in general, so forgive my noob question below, but I really do need help.

I have designed a database with 4 tables. I have created an application in C# which will store some values in these 4 tables during the course of the application running. However, this is all working fine when there is only one user of the application, but if more that one user is going to use the same application running in an ASP.NET page, then they will be accessing and altering the data in the 4 tables, and problems will soon arise.

My question is, how do I prevent this from happening? I want each user to have their own unique username and then use that to differentiate them in the tables but my knowledge of databases is limited to know how to achieve this. Please help?

Comment: If you would open up your connections when needed, and close them as soon as you're done, nothing really can happen. The odds of multiple users opening up connections and inserting data at the exact same time are extremely low. You could also create a locking mechanism which opens up the connection to the database for user #1, and you can show an error to your other users or let the application wait if a lock is in place.

Comment: @Stefan I think he's worried about users being able to view each other's data, not that he's worried about concurrent transactions.

Comment: @DaveZych that's another way to interpret the question, indeed. I guess the question doesn't provide any clarity as to what is really asked.

Comment: Ok let me explain further. My application is using the database to store the values of it's variables, as a temporary storage in the database tables. The only data that is static is the information in one of the tables which is used to populate the application. The rest of the tables vary according to the user selections on the application.

What I want is to allow any number of users to access my application whether concurrently or independently, and yet still allow them to access the same tables without creating multiple instances of the same set of tables. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 6):

Supposing you have the following table today:

```
FavoriteFood
—————————————
FoodId
FoodName
```

And it lists all of *your* favorite foods.  But then you decide you'll let me use your database to store *my* favorite foods too. Since you don't care about my favorite foods, and I don't care about yours, you need a way of keeping them separate.  First, you'll create a `User` table:

```
User
—————————
UserId
UserName
FirstName
LastName
```

Then, you need to relate the `User` table to the `FavoriteFood` table.  One way of doing this would be to add a Foreign Key to the `FavoriteFood` table.  Give it a new field called `UserId`:

```
FavoriteFood
—————————————
FoodId
UserId
FoodName
```

Then you can get just the food for a single user by adding a `WHERE` clause to your SQL code:

```sql
SELECT FoodName
  FROM FavoriteFood
 WHERE UserId = @UserId
```

That could be ok, but I'm not satisfied with it.  This database is not normalized!  Suppose, you later want to store calorie information about your foods.  You add a field called `calories` to your `FavoriteFoods` table.  As you are populating that field with data, you notice that you are putting in the same data multiple times.  All of your users like bananas, so you have as many entries in your table for bananas as you have users.  You have to enter the exact same calorie information over and over again.  Instead, you should have all the information for a food in the table just once, and use a completely separate table to map food to users:

```
Food
—————————
FoodId
FoodName
Calories

FavoriteFood
—————————————
FoodId
UserId
```

Use a join to get the favorite food for a user:

```sql
SELECT f.FoodName
      ,f.Caloires
  FROM Food f
  JOIN FavoriteFood a ON a.FoodId = f.FoodId
 WHERE a.UserId = @UserId
```

Comment: Thank you for this reply, although I need to learn more about foreign keys before I can be sure this solution fits my application.